# How to build a grid drag and drop in Angular material instead just sorting a list

Tags: angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop, grid, drag

As per angular material documentation, there is not a pure way to make a grid drag & drop. So one solution I am  thinking is a bit tricky, but enough for my feature. It's about multiple horizontal list(where I can dragging just in its own row). In the end It looks like a common grid. I have the row and column position of each grid's element, what means I split as much rows I have. Let's say there are 4 elements:

```
const Grid = [
    {
        name: "hello",
        row: 1,
        column: 1,
    },
    {
        name: "world",
        row: 1,
        column: 2,
    },
    {
        name: "I am",
        row: 2,
        column: 1,
    },
    {
        name: "here",
        row: 2,
        column: 2,
    }
]
```

So I will have 1 Array for each row, then it will roam in template as per code below:

```
<div
    *ngFor="let row of Grid; let i = index"
    cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal"
    cdkDropList
    class="flex list-section"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event, i)">
    <app-fields
        class="list-box"
        cdkDrag
        *ngFor="let groupData of row"
        [groupData]="groupData">
    </app-fields>
</div>

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>, idx?: number) {
      moveItemInArray(this.rows[idx], event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
  }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPvs2.png)

My question is. Is there a cleaner way of this approach? or Maybe use another library?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if [this old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315566/angular-material-drag-and-drop-multi-row-list/60316486#60316486) can help you. The idea is that each item was a cdkDragList

Answer (score 1):

With angular material it can be hard to use drag n drop with a grid. But the [ngx-explorer-dnd](https://github.com/Flo0806/ngx-explorer-dnd) library can help you. I'm the author and the lib is inspired from cdkDrag.

You can test it on [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wsegkg?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

It's a alpha at this time but in active development!

P.S. Animation when a element is moved will come in the next update.

[image]