# Angular CDK Drag and Drop in a 2 D array list and automatically taking the col space of the dragged element in the dropped place

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I am trying to create a dynamic template in angular using a 2D Array list, I used CDK drag and drop for dragging and dropping the element, but I am facing issues while dragging and dropping.

My HTML Code

```
<div *ngFor="let i of data" class="col-12 pt-4">
  <div
    class="row"
    cdkDropList
    [cdkDropListData]="data"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="onDrop($event)"
  >
    <div *ngFor="let j of i" [ngClass]="j.col" cdkDrag>
      <mat-card style="height: 400px"> {{j.name}} </mat-card>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My TS file code

```
export class CdkDragDropConnectedSortingExample {


     data: any = [
    [
      {
        id: 1,
        col: 'col-6',
        name: 'Chart 1'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        col: 'col-6',
        name: 'Chart 2'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 3,
        col: 'col-4',
        name: 'Chart 3'
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        col: 'col-4',
        name: 'Chart 4'
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        col: 'col-4',
        name: 'Chart 5'
      }
    ],
    [
      {
        id: 6,
        col: 'col-6',
        name: 'Chart 6'
      },
      {
        id: 7,
        col: 'col-6',
        name: 'Chart 7'
      }
    ]
  ]

  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {

    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to know how I can do drag and drop in a 2D array list and occupy the space dynamically example: if a col-6 card moved to the col-4 area, then the col-6 card should occupy the col-4 area. [My Stackblitz code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-drag-drop-si6uoz?file=app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.html,app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.ts,app%2Fcdk-drag-drop-connected-sorting-example.css,index.html)

Comment: cdk-drag is thinking about uni-dimensional direction. I suggest an aproximation like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315566/angular-material-drag-and-drop-multi-row-list/60316486#60316486). NOTE: in github there are a [discusion](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/13372) take a look also to the response of c3rber commented on 13 Dec 2018 -he has a great [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nuiviw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)